# Telnet escape sequence for Swedish keyboard layout

Tags: windows, telnet, i18n

What is the default Telnet escape sequence in Windows XP/Vista/7 when using Swedish keyboard layout? Ctrl-] doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>¨</kbd> (i.e. the same key that is <kbd>]</kbd> on American keyboards) works for me with Windows 7 and Swedish keyboard layout.